# AttributeError when trying to access class methods that do exist

Tags: python, attributeerror, double-underscore

I am trying to write tests for class methods but when I call them I get an AttributeError which complains the methods don't exist.

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def __method_to_test(x)
        return x ** 2

Foo.__method_to_test(3)
```

The last line results in the following: AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute '__method_to_test'

Why can't I call the method?

Comment: It's a kind of "private" method. Called _mangling_. See, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Comment: `@staticmethods` != `@classmethod`. I don't remember by heart whether `@staticmethod` should work in this case, but trying `@classmethod` might help.

Comment: Call `Foo._Foo__method_to_test(3)` and you will see that the method is still there, but under a different names (prefixed by the classname and an underscore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Sven Eberth, collecting their responses here.

## Python Renames Methods That Start With A Double Underline

Starting a method with a double underline causes python to do something called [*name mangling*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) which causes the method to be renamed from `__method_to_test` to `_Foo__method_to_test`.

Call the function like this:

```
Foo._Foo__method_to_test(3)
```